# image having form fields. How¿

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

i have seen an image having form fields at this [website](http://brostyro.blogspot.com).

I this this is done with position and z-index can anyone give me more info.

Comment: You can see how it is done, so what's the question?

Comment: that is just a guess. I can't view source because i use mobile browser. May be something else is used.

Comment: Stop using upside down question marks please

Comment: i use mobile browser, upside down question mark comes first in the symbol list.

Comment: @InneedofHelp, as a web developer, you're probably going to need to use desktop browsers for some things.

Comment: i am a collage going student studing biology so i don't have a desktop and don't need a laptop.

Comment: @InneedofHelp We understand what you're saying but many of the tools you need to develop properly are only available on full operating systems. Firebug is just one example - you'll soon need a full IDE (Integrated development environment) like eclipse, visual studio, etc... If you're experienced, you might _just_ get by on a mobile for something simple but while you're learning, you don't have a chance

Answer (score 2):

With [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), you can easily inspect the [exact CSS](http://getfirebug.com/css) that applies to each element.

Comment: i am using s60 and prefer opera mobile higher than any other browser and thank you.

Comment: @InneedofHelp carrying on from my comment on your Q, if you're serious about developing, you'll need to write code that works on multiple browsers - >95% of your visitors won't be using Opera. You need to know if your code will work for them too. Also, mobile browsers are very different to desktops

Comment: i am studying biology i don't even need a mobile. And my hostel does not have much space to fit a pc.

Comment: @InneedofHelp, so go to a library or a cyber-cafe.  Using one version of one mobile browser for everything is not realistic.

Comment: well it is not realistic but i validate my code and clear confusions here. And cyber cafe is a good place for me.